# Get all email addresses from a given domain

Tags: php, email

Is it possible to list all email addresses of a given domain in PHP?  All solutions I've found are either in Python or Visual Basic, I was hoping someone has a suggestion for a PHP script that can retrieve all email addresses registered under a particular domain seeing as the existing project is already written in PHP.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't really think this is possible, other than checking email addresses manually one at a time, based on guesses. If this was possible, spammers could retrieve all Gmail/Hotmail etcetera addresses in one go. Impossible.

Comment: Say the owner of a domain would like to check all email addresses registered for bounces, and there are 100s of emails, there's no way to do this with PHP?

Comment: If you are the owner of the domain, and thus have access to the email database or the server itself you could write a script ti check if it bounces. But then you have access to that data. For a random domain you have not. You could develop a bounce check with a PHP script, but only if you have the email adresses in a specific data format.

Comment: " check all email addresses registered for bounces" does not make sense, if the domain has the address, why would there be a bounce?

Comment: Some addresses are "do not reply", and I'd like them to be tested periodically since there are many registered on our server.

Comment: @Dagon because some addresses expire etcetera?

Comment: set a single return address for outgoing mail; pipe the bounces to a script. common practice for the likes of mailing lists. actually you don't even need to set the return address if you can edit your mail servers config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"... retrieve all email addresses registered under a particular domain..."

There's no public registry of valid email addresses for a given domain. This would have to be a script that runs on your email server, reading the files locally that configure all of the user aliases and email addresses for the given domains that email server is handling. This would depend on the type of email server software running on the server, and the server operating system, etc.

It can be done in PHP, but there's no way to do it for any domain publicly -- it would have to be done for your server specifically, and run locally on that server with appropriate permissions to read the key configuration files.

Comment: Ah ok, I was hoping to set up a portal for other admins and moderators to periodically check for bounces, however it seems like they would need exclusive access to the server.